# Publish libraries to another directory

Tags: .net, winforms, libraries, publish

Is it possible to publish WinForms application (.NET 6) to different directory than rest of dlls? I know that i can publish as single file, but it is not what I'm looking for.

For example:

```
/app/app.exe
/app/lib/dapper.dll
/app/lib/oracle.dll
/app/lib/system*.dll
```